# PublicClientApplication fails with Build

Tags: uwp, azure-ad-msal

Working code for PublicClientApplication has become obsolete.

Here is my code with working code commented out.

```
private Lazy<ActivationService> _activationService;

    private static string ClientId = "xxxxa4af-a717-4141-xxxxxxx";
    private static PublicClientApplication _clientApp;
    public static PublicClientApplication PublicClientApp { get { return _clientApp; } }

    private ActivationService ActivationService
    {
        get { return _activationService.Value; }
    }

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Deferred execution until used. Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx for further info on Lazy<T> class.
        _activationService = new Lazy<ActivationService>(CreateActivationService);


        //This used to work but now obsolete
        //  _clientApp = new PublicClientApplication(ClientId, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common");

       _clientApp = new PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId).Build();
```

I'm trying to get the new PublicClientApplication to work with my Url and ClientId.  But the configuration options don't work.

"The type name 'Create' does not existin the type PublicClientApplication."

How do I convert to the newer Builder Method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the [migration doc from msal2.x to msal3/4.x](https://github.com/azuread/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/MSAL.NET-2.x-to-MSAL.NET-3.x), which shows most of the APIs and how to move from v2 to v3/v4.

Here's [code](https://github.com/azuread/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/MSAL.NET-3-released#configuring-an-app-got-simpler) on creating the public client:

```cs
IPublicClientApplication app;
app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
        .Build();
```

And [specifically on the public client constructors](https://github.com/azuread/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/MSAL.NET-2.x-to-MSAL.NET-3.x#constructors-of-publicclientapplication)

[This](https://github.com/azuread/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/MSAL.NET-3-released#why-msalnet-moved-from-msal-2x-to-msal-3x) is interesting on the "why" behind the changes in msal3.x.

Comment: Thanks Jenny,  While researching the solution you provided, I've resorted to Microsoft Identity Client 2.7. 1.  Not a good hack I  know.

Comment: @TreyBalut if you need help w/the migration, let me know.